# Easiest way to attatch a file to email

Tags: android

i'm struggeling around with letting my app send an e-mail with an attatchment (temporarily created) from its home directory.
I always read that you should save it on SDcard and then attach it. But not everyone has an SDcard and the path differs from device to device.
When i open \Android\data, some folders seem to be public. Can't i just make it the same way, save the file in it and then attatch it? If not, what is the best way to find out the best path?
I would be thankful for every answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can check first sd card is present in the device or not by this method.

```
public static boolean isSdPresent() {

    return android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

    }
```

If SD card is present then give sd card path other wise your mobile memory path.

Comment: Thank you! But how do i get the mobile memory path? :D Is it possible to use this in all cases? Its just like 500 Bytes large